# wireless capability wont turn on with the button on the computer

Tags: windows-7, windows

I turned off my wiress capability a while back because i didnt have anything to connect to so i thought it would savw battery. Recently i go to turn it on to connect to a router access point for internet and the wifi switches from off to disabled and wont turn back on. I have windows 7 on a hewlett packard probook 4530s and from what i can tell theres no button on it to toggle it other than the light up button on the keyboard area above the keyboard. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the device manager if the Wi-Fi adapter is enabled? You can find that from Computer>right click>manage>device manager. Check if the adapter is enabled. If not, right click and enable it. And check again. If that too doesn't work, open up a "Run" window, put in "ncpa.cpl" (the network interface manager) and check what it shows for the particular port. Let me know after these steps.